What should I add to the ID parameter in Youtube Analytics API to get information from all the video in the world?
I am trying to get the Top 100 Most Viewed Youtube video when given a country(e.g US). When I was researching on google I found that I need to use these parameters:
dimensions=video
metrics=views,estimatedMinutesWatched,likes,subscribersGained
filters=continent==150     maxResults=10     sort=-views
Although it doesn't mention anything about what to add for id.
I already tried to directly remove the ID tag(or change it to global), although I get this error:
Traceback (most recent call last):       File "/Users/aaravsharma/PycharmProjects/YouTube Analytics Project/main.py", line 33, in.     <module>        execute_api_request(      File "/Users/aaravsharma/PycharmProjects/YouTube Analytics Project/main.py", line 23, in     execute_api_request          ).execute()       ^^^^^^^^^        File "/Users/aaravsharma/PycharmProjects/YouTube Analytics Project/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/googleapiclient/_helpers.py", line 130, in positional_wrapper         return wrapped(*args, **kwargs)            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^       File "/Users/aaravsharma/PycharmProjects/YouTube Analytics  Project/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/googleapiclient/http.py", line 938, in execute          raise HttpError(resp, content, uri=self.uri)     googleapiclient.errors.HttpError: <HttpError 400 when requesting    https://youtubeanalytics.googleapis.com/v2/reports?startDate=2017-01-01&endDate=2017-12-  31&metrics=estimatedMinutesWatched%2Cviews%2Clikes%2CsubscribersGained&dimensions=day&sort=day&al. t=json returned "Required". Details: "[{'message': 'Required', 'domain': 'global', 'reason':   'required'}]">
Does anyone know a parameter to add to the ID so I can get the world wide statistics?
The code I am using is here:
`# -- coding: utf-8 --
import os
import google.oauth2.credentials
import google_auth_oauthlib.flow
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from googleapiclient.errors import HttpError
from google_auth_oauthlib.flow import InstalledAppFlow

SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/yt-analytics.readonly']

API_SERVICE_NAME = 'youtubeAnalytics'
API_VERSION = 'v2'
CLIENT_SECRETS_FILE = 'client_secret_73871116739-            tb1crfu00qsqg0i8n244l412pgab58p4.apps.googleusercontent.com.json'
def get_service():
  flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(CLIENT_SECRETS_FILE, SCOPES)
  credentials = flow.run_local_server(port=0)
  return build(API_SERVICE_NAME, API_VERSION, credentials = credentials)

def execute_api_request(client_library_function, **kwargs):
  response = client_library_function(
    **kwargs
  ).execute()

  print(response)

if __name__ == '__main__':
  # Disable OAuthlib's HTTPs verification when running locally.
  # *DO NOT* leave this option enabled when running in production.
  os.environ['OAUTHLIB_INSECURE_TRANSPORT'] = '1'

  youtubeAnalytics = get_service()
  execute_api_request(
      youtubeAnalytics.reports().query,
      ids='channel==MINE',
      startDate='2017-01-01',
      vvendDate='2017-12-31',
      metrics='estimatedMinutesWatched,views,likes,subscribersGained',
      dimensions='day',
      sort='day'
  )`

Please provide any support to get the statistics for the 100 viewed in a country(e.g US).
Some useful links that may help are below:
.   https://developers.google.com/youtube/analytics/channel_reports#geographic-reports      https://developers.google.com/youtube/analytics/sample-requests#channel-geographic-reports      https://developers.google.com/youtube/analytics/reference/reports/query?    apix=true&apix_params=%7B%22metrics%22%3A%22estimatedMinutesWatched%2Cviews%2Clikes%2CsubscribersGained%22%2C%22dimensions%22%3A%22video%22%2C%22maxResults%22%3A%2210%22%2C%22sort%22%3A%22-estimatedMinutesWatched%22%2C%22startDate%22%3A%222023-01-01%22%2C%22endDate%22%3A%222023-06-30%22%2C%22ids%22%3A%22channel%3D%3DMINE%22%7D#python 
Note - I am using the Youtube Analytics API in the Python Programming Language.
Thanks for your help in Advance!
